# Почему перенесённые вопросы продолжают висеть на исходном сайте?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, перенос-вопросов

Недавно на Мете был задан (вероятно ошибочно) вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6555/%d0%a3%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-bootstrap-carousel, который в последствии был перенесён на основной сайт. Тем не менее он пока продолжает оставаться в списке вопросов Меты.

> [image: перенесённый вопрос]

Нормально ли такое поведение или всё же вопросы, для которых исходный сайт выбран *однозначно* ошибочно, стоит удалять таким образом, чтобы они не были видны (хотя бы на главной сайта, где их разместили первично)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Со временем (не помню, месяц или полгода) сам исчезнет. Это сделано чтобы автор вопроса смог его найти. При попытке открыть такой вопрос происходит редирект к его новому расположению.

Comment: Автор может найти свои сообщения через профиль всегда. Мне казалось, Николай, удалял форсированно как-то такие вопросы.

Comment: Ну удалить можно, но система сама удалит со временем.

Comment: ну вот с Меты было бы неплохо килять, там не так много вопросов, чтобы их нетаматичными вопросами разбавлять. В общем, можно считать это запросом на удаление, ну и в будущем делать по такой схеме.