# Удалять оригиналы (явно оффтопичных) сообщений, перенесённых с Меты

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, мета, удаление-вопросов, перенос-вопросов

Сейчас возникла ситуация, похожая на старую [Почему перенесённые вопросы продолжают висеть на исходном сайте?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6556/176217). На Мете висит вопрос явно не по теме:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ситуация немного отличается. Перенесённый на основной сайт вопрос в последствии [был удалён автором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1501457/176217).

Получаем забавную ситуацию: на сайте, для которого вопрос подходит (основной сайт), он не виден — удалён автором. А на сайте, для которого он явно не соответствует (Мета), продолжает висеть заголовок.

Поведение, кмк, странное и я запросил уточнение поэтому на MSE: [Post deleted after migration didn't result in migration rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387135/339911)

Но помимо этого я предлагаю всё же такие вопросы (очевидный оффтопик) удалять принудительно (модераторы, ау) с Меты. А не ждать пока оно само уедет вниз или удалится через месяц.

Comment: а флаг повешен? мне все же кажется, что это "исключительная" ситуация и обрабатываться должна флагами по каждому редкому случаю.

Comment: @AntonMenshov флаг как бы не на что вешать. Ну и я почему-то считаю это очевидным для удаления с Меты. Правда, допускаю, что раз модераторам видно всё равно, то они и не удаляют. Для них как бы ничего не изменится.

Comment: А разве через месяц не удалится?

Comment: Я полистал историю: часть таких сообщений удаляют модераторы (шок), часть — Дух сообщества.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ лично с моей точки зрения, проактивность модератора не всегда хорошо. В некоторых ситуациях - да. Чаще всего — есть флаги, вопросы на мете, чтобы было принято конкретное решение, особенно, когда нет четкой и часто применяемой процедуры или большого вреда от неразрешения вопроса "в данную секунду".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я дорвался до модераторства, поэтому буду стараться подобное отслеживать самостоятельно и удалять, дабы не засоряло главную.

Разок уже проверил. Полёт нормальный.

Comment: "дабы не засоряло главную" - чем вам мешают 1-2 вопроса на главной? А через 30 дней вопрос удалит дух.

Comment: @Зонтик если заходить на Мету раз в месяц, то, конечно, не мешает. Если каждый день, то мешает, ибо явно оффтоп.

Comment: Захожу на мету каждый день, не мешает)

Comment: @Зонтик завидую!

Answer (score 2):

Тут суть в том, что это не "оригинал", а заглушка, которая нужна, чтобы существующие ссылки на перенесённый вопрос раньше времени не превратились в тыкву. Поэтому она удаляется автоматически только через 30 дней: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

> Если вопросу более 30 дней и он...
> он был закрыт и перенесен на другой сайт Сети;
> … такой вопрос будет удален.

Вручную удалять их не нужно, даже если вопрос удален на своем новом месте обитания, кое-кто видеть его может. Поэтому эта заглушка должна поболтаться еще месяц. Особой проблемы в этом нет.

Comment: О каких ссылках-тыквах речь? Зачем они нужны, если ТС принял решение удалить вопрос?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ о ссылке на исходный вопрос до переноса, URL вида `https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/....`, который может остаться у кого-то в комментариях, чате, истории браузера. Только я ошибся, заглушка нужна не для перенаправления, скорее для информации, чтобы можно было увидеть вопрос как он был до миграции.

Comment: Я представляю два сценария: 1. вопрос не мигрировал и автор его удалил. 2. вопрос мигрировал и автор его удалил. В обоих сценариях я ожидаю, что вопрос будет виден только участникам 10к+ и только по прямой ссылке. Я не понимаю почему миграция (по сути раздвоение вопроса) должна оставлять какие-то неудалённые (видимые всем) копии (пусть и не полностью, а только в виде заголовков в списке вопросов).